# animated navigation background at top of site

Tags: javascript, html

I have a top page navigation where I want it to have a transparent background when at the top of the screen, then a white background when the user scrolls down.

The code I have works, however I want it to animate, which doesn't work as I have it since the class gets removed and the animation doesn't have time to work before the class is removed.

Looking for a better way to accomplish my goal

code

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
  $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill');
 } else {
  $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill');
 }
});
```

css

```
.bg-fill { 
  background-color: #fff; 
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
}
```

html

```
<nav id="anim-nav" class="row bg-fill">  ...
```

Comment: After testing your code with a black `body`, it seems to work fine. Can you please update your test code, so it would be able to run it as a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add transition rules to nav element and you will get fadeIn and fadeOut effect.

```
#anim-nav {
    height: 60px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.35s ease;
}

.bg-fill { 
    background-color: #aaa; 
}
```

Having it on toggled class will animate it just on adding class, adding it to element itself will animate it on adding and removing class.

EDIT:

[Working pen](https://codepen.io/mnikolaus/pen/RQzMQR)

Comment: This won't start off transparent though, or be transparent when page is reloaded

Comment: @user3550879 sure it will! You just have to remove your bg-fill class from html. I updated answer with working codepen.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myAnim() {
var e = document.getElementById("anim-nav");
var pos = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        pos++;
        e.style.top = pos + 'px';
        e.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
 }
```